# How to select JSON (dynamic) Parent and Child in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, timestamp

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-05-31",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Time Series": {
        "2017-05-31": {
            "1. open": "145.1000",
            "2. high": "156.6500",
            "3. low": "144.2700",
            "4. close": "152.7600",
            "5. volume": "652734610"
        },
        "2017-04-28": {
            "1. open": "143.7100",
            "2. high": "145.4600",
            "3. low": "140.0600",
            "4. close": "143.6500",
            "5. volume": "373272701"
        },
        "2017-03-31": {
            "1. open": "137.8900",
            "2. high": "144.5000",
            "3. low": "137.0500",
            "4. close": "143.6600",
            "5. volume": "562091214"
        }
    }
}
```

I managed to select the "Monthly Time Series" children with this piece of code:

```
$url = "http:...";   //some URL
$json = file_get_contents($url);   //get URL content

$data = json_decode($json,true);   //decode JSON
$arr = $data['Monthly Time Series'];   //Ignore the part before 'Monthly Time Series'

$someArray = $arr;   // Loop through the JSON array
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "[" .$value["1. open"] . ", " . $value["2. high"] . ", " . $value["3. low"] . ", " . $value["4. close"] . ", " . $value["5. volume"] . "],\n";
  }

echo $somearray;
```

And my output comes like this:

```
[145.1000, 156.6500, 144.2700, 152.7600, 652734610],
[143.7100, 145.4600, 140.0600, 143.6500, 373272701],
[137.8900, 144.5000, 137.0500, 143.6600, 562091214]
```

I don't really understand how I can select the dates as well. In fact I need the parent (date) included together with my children (values). And the date needs to be translated into a timestamp. So the result would look like this:

```
[1496181600, 145.1000, 156.6500, 144.2700, 152.7600, 652734610],
[1493330400, 143.7100, 145.4600, 140.0600, 143.6500, 373272701],
[1490911200, 137.8900, 144.5000, 137.0500, 143.6600, 562091214]
```

I believe that formatting of the time is done with PHP's

```
strtotime
```

but I don't understand how I get the JSON parent into the same array parenthesis with it's children.

Any input from your side is highly appreciated. Please bare in mind that I'm an absolute PHP (and JS) newbee..

Comment: when you do `foreach($var as $key=>$value)` you loop through all the rows of $var, and can get the $key as well as the $value, in your case, the value is an array, and your date string is simply in the $key var. You can just then convert it to timestamp and include in your output

Comment: @SahilGulati: My expected output includes the DATE as timestamp inside the parenthesis'. The first value is the date as timestamp, followed by the JSON child values: [1496181600, 145.1000, 156.6500, 144.2700, 152.7600, 652734610],
[1493330400, 143.7100, 145.4600, 140.0600, 143.6500, 373272701],
[1490911200, 137.8900, 144.5000, 137.0500, 143.6600, 562091214]

Comment: @Kaddath: Can you maybe show me how your solution looks coded? I'm not fully following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two concise ways (one is commented out) to use a `foreach()` loop to achieve the desired result. ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a1ef67eb26f778c43949de63dda6fdd12bb8bfc)):

```
$data=json_decode($json,true);
$arr=$data['Monthly Time Series'];
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $result[]='['.strtotime($k).', '.implode(', ',$v).']';  // avoid naming each element
    // or $result[]='['.implode(', ',[strtotime($k)]+$v).']'; // merge then implode()
}
echo implode(",\n",$result);  // no trailing comma on the final row
```

Output:

```
[1496214000, 145.1000, 156.6500, 144.2700, 152.7600, 652734610],
[1493362800, 143.7100, 145.4600, 140.0600, 143.6500, 373272701],
[1490943600, 137.8900, 144.5000, 137.0500, 143.6600, 562091214]
```

---

Now if you are going to be passing this data to javascript and want to create a JSON array of arrays, you can use the earlier defined `$arr` with one of these methods:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$a){
    $result[]=[strtotime($k)]+array_values($a);  // merge the reformatted key with the values
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

or a function-based approach with no result array variable declared:

```
$json=json_encode(
        array_map(
            function($key,$values){
                return [strtotime($key)]+array_values($values);  // merge
            },
            array_keys($arr),  // the keys
            array_column($arr,null)  // the values
        )
    );
echo $json;
// This method doesn't need to declare $json, it can be directly var_exported.
// I mere declared $json for consistency / comprehension.
```

Both of these json-outputting methods will yield:

```
[[1496214000,"156.6500","144.2700","152.7600","652734610"],[1493362800,"145.4600","140.0600","143.6500","373272701"],[1490943600,"144.5000","137.0500","143.6600","562091214"]]
```

Here is a new [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e73736ed849d05dfce8a1b81ae71e61b4ef0938).
Notice the extra `[` and `]` wrapping the result; this makes the data an array with multiple arrays inside.
Also notice that the values after the strtotime date are double-quoted as strings.  This means future data handling won't accidentally remove any trailing zero -- assuming they are important to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope this will be helpful. Add this to your code `strtotime($key)`

I dont know what you are trying to do. Instead i recommend to use **`json_encode`**.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/820377)

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$arr = $data['Monthly Time Series'];

$result=array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $result[]=  sprintf("[%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s]",
                    strtotime($key),
                    $value["1. open"],
                    $value["2. high"],
                    $value["3. low"],
                    $value["4. close"],
                    $value["5. volume"]);

}
print_r(join(",\n",$result));
```